# Conditional formatting of axis text using ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am attempting to format the axis text to reflect the same groups used
to fill the geom in the plot below. The color scheme is picked up for the fill argument
in aes(), resulting in different colors between a and b, c. The ifelse statement used in 
element_text() does not result in correct color formating, however.

```
library(ggplot2)

# Make some data (emulating melted format)
df <- cbind.data.frame(c('a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'c'), 
                       c(5, 5, 5, 15, 45), 
                       c(1, 1, 1, 0, 0))
names(df) <- c('variable', 'value', 'col')

# Conditional statement to be used in plot
con <- ifelse(df$col == 1, 'red', 'green')

# Call to the plot included below
ggplot(df, aes(x = variable, y = value)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", aes(fill = col)) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1, colour = con))
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `con` variable has five elements, the first three of which are "red":

```
[1] "red"   "red"   "red"   "green" "green"
```

Since there are only three axis labels, `theme` uses the first three values, thus making all labels red. When `con` is of the proper length, we get the desired result:

```
con <- ifelse(unique(df$variable) == 'a', 'red', 'darkgreen')
```

[image]